# How to index a sequence of macros

Tags: c, macros

Suppose I have the following macros defined:

```
#define TEST0  100
#define TEST1  101
...
#define TEST9  109
```

And assume I have an int representing the index of such a macro:

```
int idx=3;
```

Is there a way to access TEST3 given that idx is equal to 3?

This code works fine because here I pass a value known at compile time:

```
#define TEST(id) (TEST##id)
printf("Retrieved value: %d\n",TEST(3));
```

But I haven't found a way to do the same with a variable, i.e.:

```
printf("Retrieved value: %d\n",TEST(i));
```

Adding a level of indirection with

```
#define STR_INDIR(x) #x
#define STR(x) STR_INDIR(x)
```

also doesn't help here because this evaluation occurs at compile time.

One possibility is to create a C function with a switch statement:

```
int test(int x) {
    switch(x) {
        case 0: return TEST0;break;
        case 1: return TEST1;break;
...
        case 9: return TEST9;break;
    }
}
```

But that doesn't scale well...

Comment: How about `#define TEST(id) (100+(id))`?

Comment: You've already noted why this is impossible: macro names only exist for the preprocessor and don't exist at runtime.  In almost all cases where you think you want a numbered sequence of variables, with the ability to access them by number, then what you want instead is usually an array: `const int test[] = { [0] = 100, [1] = 101, ... };`

Comment: The best thing here is probably not to use macros at all.

Comment: If you use GCC then it has an extension to the language, with a special `__COUNTER__` macro which is increased for very use in a single translation unit. See [the GCC online documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html) for more information.

Comment: Regarding suggestions for not using macros or redefining the TEST(id) as 100+(id), the issue is that I do not control the file defining these macros, and their values isn't as trivial as a simple increment by 100, which was just an example here.

Comment: Thanks @NateEldredge. That is what I needed to confirm. I was hoping there was some way around this but this is inherent to what a macro is.

Answer (score 0):

Macro `TEST` could expand to a cascade of conditional expressions (`?:`).

```
#define TEST(v)       \
  ((v) == 0 ? TEST0 : \
   (v) == 1 ? TEST1 : \
   (v) == 2 ? TEST2 : \
   -1)
```

For example `int j = TEST(i);` expands to

```
int j = ((i) == 0 ? 100 : (i) == 1 ? 101 : (i) == 2 ? 102 : -1);
```

The solution works for variable `i` as well as for any integer expression as well. Compiler should be able to optimize the code to avoid unncessary comparison if it is possible.
However, the side effects may be computed multiple time, so be careful.

Additionally, if the argument is a *constant expression* then the result is a *constant expression* as well. This is not possible for functions though upcomming C23 standard will add `constexpr` to the language.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. This is similar to the switch statement I have in a C test(x) function, which I would prefer so as to not grow considerably the size of my code for each call made to that TEST(v) macro.